# Failed to decode bitmap from an image file

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-image

I am trying to download images from URL. The image type is PNG and the resolution is 400x400 pixels.

Here is the download code snippet.

```
Bitmap bitmap=null;
URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
InputStream ins=conn.getInputStream();
os = new FileOutputStream(f);
Utilities.getUtilities().copyStream(ins, os);
os.flush();

Log.i(TAG_NAME, "file size : "+ f.length());
Log.i(TAG_NAME, "file exists in cache? " + f.exists());
bitmap = decodeFile(f);
return bitmap;
```

Here is the file writer.

```
public void copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
  final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the decode method

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
   //decode image size
   BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   try {
     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 400; //for testing, it is set to b a constant
   System.out.println("REQUIRED_SIZE >>> " + REQUIRED_SIZE);
   int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
   int scale=1;
   while(true){
      if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
      width_tmp/=2;
      height_tmp/=2;
        scale*=2;
    }

    //decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //o2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    o2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    o2.inSampleSize=scale; //scale is set off since android:src automatically scales the image to fit the screen

    try {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I can see that the file exists in the device. However, the decode stream is failing. I spent hours searching on the internet; tried almost everything, no success and almost my heads rolling.

Decode streams is causing the following error.

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Do you find anything missing here?

**EDIT:**

Issue is now solved. The server was expecting cookie details which I failed to attach. Spent almost a day, beating around the bushes :-)

Thanks all for the valuable comments!

Comment: Any error or it just return null? If error, post logcat info.

Comment: sorry about that! Oops left out, Question edited!

Comment: Hope you have already tried out the solution mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006785/android-skimagedecoder-factory-returned-null)

Comment: @PCoder Yes I did and it didn't get me through!

Comment: How can you check if the downloaded file is not corrupted?

Comment: Try closing the file after the flush, but before the decode.

Comment: Try recycling your File object (ie by constructing a new one). I had this problem where the first (size-based) decode made the underlying inputstream no longer return any more data during the second decode.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you may want to re-evaluate merits of httpurlconn vs native [httpclient](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) implementation. Android/google go for httpurlconn but, many opt to take greater control of low level details surrounding net protocol.

Here is [sample async](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/) httpclient that wraps in bitmap handler. You can easily extend the sample `method=processBitmapEntity()` with your rules affecting bmp size.

Sample getbitmap url:

```
  public  int getBitmap(String mediaurl, int ctr){

           Handler handler = new Handler() {
               public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                 switch (message.what) {
                 case HttpConnection.DID_START: {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Starting connection...");
                   break;
                 }
                 case HttpConnection.DID_SUCCEED: {
                     //message obj is type bitmap
                     Log.d(TAG, "OK bmpARRAY " +message.arg1); 
                    Bitmap response = (Bitmap) message.obj;
                   break;
                 }
                 case HttpConnection.DID_ERROR: {

                   Exception e = (Exception) message.obj;
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed.");
                   break;
                 }
               }
             }
           };        
           new HttpConnection(handler, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this), ctr).bitmap(mediaurl);

       return -1;
```

And the bitmap handler in HttpConnection class that is part of the link sample above:

```
private void processBitmapEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IOException {
    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
    handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, DID_SUCCEED, bm));
}
```

And a [git project](https://github.com/rowntreerob/gpsclipper/blob/master/src/com/b2bpo/media/geophoto/HttpConnection.java)