# not able to get File from JSonObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have Array of files (images) at localdataStore of parse.com and I want to fetch file from there, I have implemented following code...

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Test_class");

query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "SSDW232sda");
query.fromLocalDatastore();

    try{
        List<ParseObject> objects = queryChild.find();
        System.out.println(objects.size());
        ParseObject object = objects.get(0);


        JSONArray imagesArr = object.getJSONArray("images");

        for(int i=0;i<imagesArr.length();i++){
            try {
                ParseFile image =  (ParseFile) imagesArr.getJSONObject(i).get("name");//.getParseFile("name");
                byte[] img = image.getData();
                bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img , 0, img.length));
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("could not get image");
            }
        }


    }catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it gives the following error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseFile
```

help me to fix this problem..

Comment: the error which I mention above is log cat error...  what response you are asking?

Comment: You get this because imagesArr.getJSONObject(i).get("name") returns a String object. Maybe the name of the file? Do a printline on imagesArr.getJSONObject(i).get("name") to see what you get. Also, you should include the code where the image array is written to localdatastore

Answer (score 1):

Here's the spec for [JSON](http://www.json.org/). There isn't a `ParseFile` object in there.

You probably want to get the `String` from JSON, convert it into a byte array, then call the `ParseFile` constructor.

Ex.

```
String stringFromJson = json.getString("whatever_key_you_need");
byte[] stringFromJsonAsByteArray = stringFromJson.getBytes();

ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("filename.txt", stringFromJsonAsByteArray);
```

Comment: getting values correctly but when convert to bitmap and set to ImageView then shows empty boxes...

Comment: You sure you want a `ParseFile` and not a `ParseImageView`? Have a look at their docs on it :: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

Comment: I am converting byteArray to bitmap and the set it to imageView, but nothing I can see...

Comment: it gives  --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: Maybe this can help :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006785/android-skimagedecoder-factory-returned-null