# Android SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null Error

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm trying to load an image from URL to an ImageView but the error occurs:
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null. How can I fix it?

here is my code :

```
private class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        ImageView bitmapImgView;
        public LoadImageFromURL(ImageView bmImgView){
            bitmapImgView = bmImgView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String urlStr = params[0];
            Bitmap img = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                //Options bmFactoryOpt = new Options();
                //bmFactoryOpt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);          
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
            bitmapImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved. Change the code to this.

```
@Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String urlStr = params[0];
            Bitmap img = null;

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = (HttpResponse)client.execute(request);           
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                InputStream inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return img;
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me after a whole day of trying other solutions.

Comment: @johnson Just create a class that extends AsyncTask like Simon has in his question. In the button's click event, create a new instance of your class and execute it. The Android docs have more information http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You sir rock! This works great for getting facebook user profile images etc!

Comment: Its working perfect but I don't know the exact reason of issue & resolution.