# How to remove html tags from listview?

Tags: android, html, json, listview

I am using json parsing and I am getting response from server and in my response it contains some html tags,and it displays in my listview..I am using imageview and textview in my listview..how to remove html tags?

response

```
[  
{  
 "title_tag":"business",  
"description":"<p>\r\n\t<strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong> is simply dummy   text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/p>\r\n",  
  "image":"1.jpg"    

    }  
    ]
```

Myadapter

```
public class CustomAdapterAdvertisement extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData;
private AQuery aQuery;

private static final String ADD_NAME="title_tag";
private static final String ADD_DESC="description";
private static final String ADD_IMAGE="image";

public CustomAdapterAdvertisement(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listData=listData;
    aQuery = new AQuery(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public String stripHtml(String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.advertisement_detail, null);
        holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.advertisement_img);
        holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtnameadvertisement);
       // holder.txtproid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproidsearch);
        holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtadvertisementdescription);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position).get(ADD_NAME));
    //holder.txtproid.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_PROFILE));
    holder.txtprofilecast.setText(listData.get(position).get(ADD_DESC));
   holder.txtprofilecast.setText(Html.fromHtml("description").toString());

    aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(ADD_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // image parameter : 1 : memory cache,2:file cache,3:target width,4:fallback image


    return convertView;
}
class ViewHolder{
    ImageView propic;
    TextView txtproname;
   // TextView txtproid;
    TextView txtprofilecast;

}
```

}

Comment: why downvote??did i ask something wrong?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to remove html tags from listview?

As in provided `description` key text all html tags are supported by [Html.fromHtml](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).

To show html formatted text in  TextView use `Html.fromHtml`:

```
String strDes=Html.fromHtml(description).toString();
```

Comment: i am using base adapter my listitems..and my activity file and baseadapter file is seprate..where can i use your code?

Comment: @fazilpuriasa : In adapter textView in which currently you are  `description` value . add it as `textview_in_getview_method.setText(Html.fromHtml(description).toString())`

Comment: my adapter file is same as like this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576379/how-to-download-image-and-save-in-gallery

Comment: @fazilpuriasa: In `business_card.xml` layout in which TextView you want to show `description` string?

Comment: business card is different module..i already completed that..i shre link so that you can get idea about my base adapter class..and as you said i added this line  holder.txtprofilecast.setText(Html.fromHtml("description").toString());...but all text disappear

Comment: @fazilpuriasa: Use `holder.txtprofilecast.setText(Html.fromHtml(listData.get(position).get(ADD_DESC)).toString());`

Comment: @fazilpuriasa: means i'm not getting you?

Comment: ammm nothing i copy your text and paste in my code..and then i press ctrl+s and eclipse creating problem for saving..but it solved now works fine..thanks..all html tag gone..

Comment: can you help me with this??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299839/file-is-not-sending-to-php-server

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution as below

you can try the following, create class in your package and name it "Util"

```
public class Util{
public static String stripHtml(String html) 
{
  //html = "<p sapn = 'div'>hhhhhhhhh<p> Hello World </p></span>";
  while(html.contains("<"))
    html = html.replace(html.substring(html.indexOf("<"),html.indexOf(">")+1),"");
  return html;//will return hhhhhhhh Hello World
}
}
```

this method will search for any text that begins with "<" and ends with ">" and it will replace it.

then you can use the method anywhere you want

```
String myNewStringWithoutHTML = Util.stripHtml(STRING);
```

Hope above solution will help you.

Let me know if need more help for same from my side on same.

Comment: Your welcome and if you need more help then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
var book = {  
 "title_tag":"business",  
"description":"<p>\r\n\t<strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong> is simply dummy   text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/p>\r\n",  
  "image":"1.jpg"    

    } 

$(function(){
    $('body').append("<div class='text'>"+book.description+"</div>");
    alert($('.text').text());
    $('.text').hide();
})
```