# upload an image from the link to the gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview

I'm trying to download the image from the link to the gallery

this codes not working

```
RxVolley.download(FileUtils.getSDCardPath() + "/Wallpaper/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"
                        , "http://......"
                        , new ProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(long transferredBytes, long totalSize) {

                            }
                        }, new HttpCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String t) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "下载成功", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "下载失败", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

are there other codes working for example asycn task etc... , I hope help me

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Please View This post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576379/download-image-and-save-in-gallery

Comment: request this method everytime onFailure

Comment: Can you show me error msg?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/x1JZg