# Image URL entered In editText on a imageView

Tags: java, android

When the user clicks this button the app should retrieve the image from the web. It should do this in a separate thread and When the image is downloaded it should be displayed on the same Screen using ImageView.I can't seem to get it to work but I feel like I'm really close can anyone help me out please? Thanks!

My Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.stephen.asyncdownloadimageurl">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My XML FIle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"
    android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:ems="10" />
```

My Jave File

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
EditText et;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
                new MyDownloadTask().execute(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class MyDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
        URL url = params[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Download Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you describe the error? no result? no data from stream? any more info on the problem?

Comment: @TannerSummers My Toast message isn't working to tell me that it has failed trying to retrieve the image but it isn't getting the image either.All my code runs but I can't seem to find the problem atm to why it's not working.

Comment: I put ur code into my pc. And works fine except i didnt us the st.getText().to string. So u may want to see if that had a value. Also if i may ask, why are you reading from a textview?

Comment: @TannerSummers so my code downloaded a image? My code doesn't contain a textview? has a button, editText and imageView?

Comment: Yes. I put a edittext button and image view. I just put ur code Exaclty as u have it and works fine. So i am not sure. Does your console (android monitor) show any errors? Is the url correct that u pass into the url object?

Comment: I also want to point out if you are typing the url in your app that's being passed to your URL object i noticed my phone auto corrects it and adds period at the end which invalidates the url. Look for something similar

Comment: @TannerSummers No errors showing up in console. If url wasn't correct the toast message would pop up and it isn't either so I'm really stumped on where I went wrong or maybe it's something to do with the phone I'm testing it on?

Comment: This one is hard to say, it works perfect for me, my only advice is

1) log the url when it gets put into the URL object to see if it is correct when in the code for whatever reason

2) can you post your xml file?

3) try a different image url

Comment: Wanted to add more, if the url was not right, the exception would be caught in your try surrounding the URL object, it would never call the async task and thus never call your toast, I would check logs again on verbose to check for anything

Comment: @TannerSummers Added my XML File. would you mind adding your version of the code to this post so I can compare. It's most likely something small that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec, also see my second added comment above your reply, about the exception

Comment: added and answer

Answer (score 2):

Use special android libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load images. It's really easy to use it, they have disk/memory cache, you can load image in separate thread without using complex solutions.

Comment: Thank you. Would that work for what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: actually I didn't get what you're trying to achieve. but it will load image in worker thread and it's the most simple thing this libraries can do

Comment: It is a great library for this case i don't think its needed. But if you do want it, it is not the hard to put in your app but we still need to figure out your issue first

Comment: while this is a good suggestion, it does not answer the question

Answer (score 2):

As you mentionned in a comment, your image is at this url

> http://tny.im/ayy

This url does not point to an image. It points to a redirects, (http status 301).

It is possible that your connection is not following redirects.

You can instruct the connection to follow the redirection by:

```
((HttpURLConnection) connection).setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Good to know about that redirect method!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is my thoughts after talking in the comments

1) I copied your code and xml EXACTLY as you posted and it WORKS fine for me, with that said I want to add a few things

EDIT: not sure if this matters but these were my imports

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
```

I think it could be a combination of these possibilities

2) make sure your url is ok, make sure you add the http or https part. make sure your auto correct does not add anything (mine added a period at the end). since this is the only part I can't test, I feel like this could be it

3) Log everything, log the url right before its passed into your URL object just to be sure it is correct, look for ANY exceptions

4) the toast will not show up if url is wrong, if url can't parse a valid URL ( like mentioned earlier), it will be caught in the try catch surrounding the URL object being created and will not call the async task (happen to me when I put fake url in and I got exception, so try keep an eye out)

EDIT: for number 4, i got exception for incorrect protocol (left out the http) but if link was wrong then yes, toast showed up

5) try another image, you never know :D

EDIT: try this with Glide,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(et.getText().toString())
                    .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

no need for async

and one more solution without Glide

```
  @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL url = params[0];
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;


            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



  return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you good sir for your time helping with this task I appreciate it. I will get to the bottom of this eventually!

Comment: Let me know, I am very curious on the issue. If we could do chat on this website, message me or something I want to help.

Comment: My toast message is showing now like you mentioned trying a new url. but it's a valid URL http://tny.im/ayy to a image so i'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: This is showing up in console when I press the button with the URL - 10-07 04:47:28.424 23415-23988/com.example.stephen.asyncdownloadimageurl D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: did you log out the url in console? I would log out the url and copy and paste it into browser and see if anything got changed and works.

Comment: After seeing this error on google, try Glide, it may be better at handling the bytes coming in , see updated post

Comment: Use the code I posted above, with Glide, I think it is something to do with how the bytes are read in, as others suggested Glide is a great lib and I posted a working example using your code above.

Comment: if not try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559736/android-skimagedecoderfactory-returned-null-error

Comment: I used: https://pixabay.com/get/eb32b80c21f6093ecd0b4306e245449ee16ae3d019b6124597f5c77c_1280.jpg

dont forget to see my updated post! sorry its been so much back and fourth

Comment: Any shorter URL's as I have to type in phone

Comment: try this, not sure if this will work but it is an image goo.gl/EV7eQ9

Comment: Thanks both valid image links but still not working for me. it's nearly 6am where I am so i'm going to bed and I will return to this tomorrow. Thanks for all the help!!. If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: I will keep helping as much as I can. Re read my suggestions and try them goodnight

Answer (score 0):

// Add following dependecny for glide

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'



new LoadImageFromUrlTask().execute(imageURL);




public class LoadImageFromUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        String downloadPath = "";
        String sdCardBasePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                downloadPath = args[0];
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(downloadPath).getContent());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                String photoFileName = downloadPath.substring(downloadPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                String saveImagePath = "";

                int dotposition = photoFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
                String filename_Without_Ext = photoFileName.substring(0, dotposition);
                String Ext = photoFileName.substring(dotposition + 1, photoFileName.length());
                String newFileName = filename_Without_Ext + "." + Ext;
                saveImagePath = sdCardBasePath + "/" + newFileName;
                saveBitmapToJPEGFile(MainActivity.this, bitmap, new File(saveImagePath), 900);
                saveBitmapToFile(MainActivity.this, myImageViewImage, saveImagePath);
            } else {
                myImageViewImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_photo);
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean saveBitmapToFile(Context ctx, Bitmap tempBitmap, File targetFile, int i) {
        Boolean result = true;
        if (tempBitmap != null) {
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                tempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, CommonUtils.JPEG_COMPRESION_RATIO_DEFAULT, out);  

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                result = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void loadImageWithGlide(Context theCtx, ImageView theImageView, String theUrl) {
        Glide.with(theCtx)
                .load(theUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(theImageView);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the code I originally posted to work even with all of you's guys help. Big thanks to anybody that posted with suggestions!!. Anyway I went back to scratch and finally got it to work with even less code!
Here's my working code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView view;
    Button btn;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFileUrl);
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieveFileUrl);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view) {

        String stringUrl = editText.getText().toString();
        new DownloadTask().execute(stringUrl);
    }


    // Uses AsyncTask to create a task away from the main UI thread. This task takes
    // URL string and uses it to create an HttpUrlConnection. Once the connection
    // has been established, the AsyncTask downloads the contents of the webpage as
    // an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream is converted into a string, which is
    // displayed in the UI by the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Create PD, SET Properties
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Image Downloader");
            pd.setMessage("Downloading....");
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0];

            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap url) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                super.onPostExecute(url);
                view.setImageBitmap(url);
                //Dismiss
                pd.dismiss();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Download Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Dismiss
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, as long as it works, to me it looks the same so not sure why but as long as it works right? anyways just one note the ProgressDialog is deprecated so just an fyi :)

Answer (score -1):

Use library like Glide. You can simply add Glide dependency in Gradle:
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

and you can load image simply by writing:
Glide.with(context).load("image_url").into(imagevie_name);

Comment: Also note there is version 4 released

Comment: I think it helps, I been trying to figure it out and it may be easier to use this but I am not sure. The OP's code works for me fine, although I do not know how big the image being pulled in the OP's example is