# How to convert image to string in Android?

Tags: android, android-image

[It's my MySql DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEF8P.png)[image: its my php page that is read streareader]
Its encoding:-

```
public String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap bmp) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String imageStr = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 1);
        return imageStr;
}
```

This is decoding:-

```
String img=o.toString();
   byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(img.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```

Thank you.

Comment: then, whats wrong with the code?

Comment: What you mean ? I dont see any question

Comment: what is o reference?

Comment: i am fetch string fro mysql db using php script but image view is going white screen

Comment: image is not showing on imageview.

Comment: First of all check your database through phpmyadmin and make sure that field is not empty. Second, set the data type of that field as BLOB (in phpmyadmin database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done by

```
private String getBase64String() {

    // give your image file url in mCurrentPhotoPath
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // In case you want to compress your image, here it's at 40%
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

And for Decode

```
private void decodeBase64AndSetImage(String completeImageData, ImageView imageView) {

    // Incase you're storing into aws or other places where we have extension stored in the starting.
    String imageDataBytes = completeImageData.substring(completeImageData.indexOf(",")+1);

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(stream)););

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(stream)););    decodeStream its error

Comment: Modified it. Check it.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062314/5747134), try flushing the input stream after every use.

Comment: I know this is kinda old, but your *decodeBase64AndSetImage* function does not return a *String*. I jsut changed the header to *void*.